# How to interact with Alarms in iOS from Unity App?

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I am starting a new Unity app for a client and i need to have a feature to manage device alarms from the app (clock alarms , not notifications).

Android is done. I can can call a method do AddAlarm() and the device default dialog opens to add alarm with the specified parameters (Description and Hour:Minutes).
But, i need this to work on iOS as well.

Probably i will need to interact with an Objective C Library, but i have no clue how to do it (sincerly).

Any Expert can help me?

I developed the android part. It's working.

Comment: There is no api on iOS for interacting with the clock app or its alarms.